# Show all posts in sidebar in single.php

Tags: posts, loop, sidebar, single

Wordpress 4.x

Why does the `loop.php` only show the current post in the sidebar when I view a post in `single.php`?

I have:

1. Post One
2. Post Two
3. Post Three

If I view "Post One" (single.php), the sidebar only shows "Post One", if I view the page I have set as the "Blog" page (index.php) in Wordpress admin, I see all the posts in the sidebar.

My goal is to have all posts show in the `single.php` sidebar. Would be nice to remove the current posts as well! But mostly want to understand the relationship/structure here.

Working with a custom theme based on the [HTML5 Blank theme](http://html5blank.com/), no major custom functionality.

First Wordpress site and this feels like a fundamental structure aspect.

**sidebar.php**

```
<aside class="sidebar column" role="complementary">

    <?php get_template_part('searchform'); ?>

    <?php get_template_part('loop'); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>

    <div class="sidebar-widget">
        <?php if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('widget-area-1')) ?>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar-widget">
        <?php if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('widget-area-2')) ?>
    </div>

</aside>
```

**loop.php**

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <article class="loop-template" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <!-- article content here -->

    </article>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>

    <article>

        <!-- else content here -->

    </article>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Then in `single.php` I am calling `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` outside of any loop or conditional.

Comment: better to post some code , it's confusing ..you might not be running inside the loop

Comment: Added what I believe is the relevant code to my question.

Comment: You have not initiated the WP query for sidebar in loop.php

Answer (score 1):

Initiating `new WP_Query($post)` shows all posts. Credit to `@Latheesh V M Villa`

Add:

```
$loop_query = new WP_Query($post)
```

Then change loop values like:

```
have_posts()
```

to:

```
$loop_query->have_posts()
```

---

**loop.php**

```
<?php $loop_query = new WP_Query($post); if ($loop_query->have_posts()): while ($loop_query->have_posts()) : $loop_query->the_post(); ?>
    <article class="loop-template" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <!-- article content here -->
    </article>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <article>
        <!-- else content here -->
    </article>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It appears you can leave everything inside the loop alone such as `the_ID()` and `the_title()`.

Great article at [smashingmagazine here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/using-wp_query-wordpress/)